# How to run an activity once in 3o mins forever android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

hi i want this code to be repeated forever, can any body help me pls i am trying a lot but i could not get an explanantion for this i cant understand how to repeate it once for half an hour using alarm method or timer.
Can anybody help me? and i dont need a service for this.

code:

```
public class gps extends Activity implements LocationListener
{
    LocationManager manager;
    String closestStation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        {
            Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cur_cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
            Log.d("Testing", "Calender Set time:" + cur_cal.getTime());
            Intent intent = new Intent(gps.this, gps_back_process.class);
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(gps.this, 0,
                intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 15, pintent);
            alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pintent);
            Log.d("Testing", "alarm manager set");
            Toast.makeText(this, "gps_back_process.onCreate()",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            this.sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
        {
            //initialize location manager
            manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            //check if GPS is enabled
            //if not, notify user with a toast
            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
            else {
                //get a location provider from location manager
                //empty criteria searches through all providers and returns the best one
                String providerName = manager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
                Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationResults);
                if (location != null) {
                    tv.setText(location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude");
                } else {
                    tv.setText("Last known location not found. Waiting for updated location...");
                }
                manager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 1000*60*30 , 1 , this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationResults);
        if (location != null) {
            tv.setText(location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude");
            // I have added this line
            appendData ( location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude" );
        } else {
           tv.setText("Problem getting gps NETWORK ID : " + "");
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}

     // Find the closest Bart Station
    public String findClosestBart(Location loc) {
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lon = loc.getLongitude();
        double curStatLat = 0;
        double curStatLon = 0;
        double shortestDistSoFar = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        double curDist;
        String curStat = null;
        String closestStat = null;
        //sort through all the stations
        // write some sort of for loop using the API.
        curDist = Math.sqrt( ((lat - curStatLat) * (lat - curStatLat)) +
                ((lon - curStatLon) * (lon - curStatLon)) );
        if (curDist < shortestDistSoFar) {
            closestStat = curStat;
        }
        return closestStat;
    }

    // method to write in file
    public void appendData(String text)
    {
        File dataFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/GpsData.txt");
        if (!dataFile.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                dataFile.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try
        {
            //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataFile, true));
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm, dd/MM/yyyy");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
           // text+=","+currentDateandTime;
            buf.append(text + "," + currentDateandTime);
            buf.newLine();
            buf.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the **6th** time you are asking this question in various forms. Some have different titles / post contents, etc. But all in all, duplicates. [Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16371053/450534), [Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16352048/450534), [Question 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16370089/450534), [Question 4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16354919/450534) _and_ [Question 5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16336028/450534).

Comment: You mean, you want an Activity to popup from nowhere on a user's device every 30 minutes? Are you sure about this?

Comment: agreed with @IceMAN .. PureIndianDeveloper read the FAQ pls... -1

Comment: i have votes -1 on same type of questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code, it looks like you are trying to fetch and log location and nearby stations every 30 minutes. You are over complicating the simple thing.

In my opinion, you should move the code for location provider to a service that will keep running in background. In service, register for location updates every 30 min (as done already). 
Every 30 min, android will call LocationListener callback methods and you can perform action accordingly (Save to file, display notification, send a message to Acivity to update UI).

Also from User perspective and as suggested by Ergo, you shouldn't pop up toast every 30 min notifying user about disabled GPS.